# Disable a button in template driven Angular

Tags: angular, templates

`<button (click) = "onSave()" [disabled]="true" > Save </button>`

All I expect is to have the button turned grey in the beginning. Even with disabled being true, I am still able to click on it and the corresponding function gets called.

Comment: if the disable is true the method will not working , is it possible to create a demo maybe there is something else not working

Comment: If I understands it correctly - [Unable to reproduce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7nvge)

Comment: Strange... this case is impossible, I think. Even when the button is disabled, how it can the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is right. Look this working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inewkb). Did you try to clear you cache on your browser?
Are you sure that your code dosen't affect the buttons and you overwrite this disable attribute?

Comment: I am thankful to you. It does show as disabled when I comment out rest of the code.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl Great!